# OrientDB: getting OLowDiskSpaceException when trying to restore a database backup

Tags: orientdb

I backed up my database and I'm now upgrading to v2.1.16.
I've tested my backup and restore routine on a local Vagrant virtual server and everything went fine.

I'm now trying to run the same procedure on my Amazon AWS server, and the process fails due to a OLowDiskSpaceException.

Here is the message I'm getting:

```
Started import of database 'remote:localhost/mydatabase' from /home/ubuntu/orientdb_
update_16.04.27.11.10.+0000.gz...
Non merge mode (-merge=false): removing all default non security classesError on
 database import happened just before line 0, column 1
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OLowDiskSpaceException: Error occurr
ed while executing a write operation to database 'mydatabase' due to limited free sp
ace on the disk (-26 MB). The database is now working in read-only mode. Please
close the database (or stop OrientDB), make room on your hard drive and then reo
pen the database. The minimal required space is 100 MB. Required space is now se
t to 100MB (you can change it by setting parameter storage.diskCache.diskFreeSpa
ceLimit) .
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginat
edStorage.checkLowDiskSpaceAndFullCheckpointRequests(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.j
ava:2890)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginat
edStorage.updateRecord(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:943)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.exe
cuteSaveRecord(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2005)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionNoTx.saveRecord(OTra
nsactionNoTx.java:159)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.sav
e(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2568)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.sav
e(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:121)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.save(ODocumen
t.java:1768)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.save(ODocumen
t.java:1764)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OSchemaShared$1.cal
l(OSchemaShared.java:1213)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OScenarioThreadLocal.executeAsDi
stributed(OScenarioThreadLocal.java:71)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OSchemaShared.saveI
nternal(OSchemaShared.java:1208)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OSchemaShared.relea
seSchemaWriteLock(OSchemaShared.java:642)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OSchemaShared.relea
seSchemaWriteLock(OSchemaShared.java:631)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OSchemaShared.dropC
lass(OSchemaShared.java:557)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OSchemaProxy.dropCl
ass(OSchemaProxy.java:156)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDropClass.ex
ecute(OCommandExecutorSQLDropClass.java:122)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.exe
cute(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:90)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginat
edStorage.executeCommand(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1547)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginat
edStorage.command(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1528)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract
.execute(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:67)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkP
rotocolBinary.command(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:1323)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkP
rotocolBinary.executeRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:400)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.OBinaryNe
tworkProtocolAbstract.execute(OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.java:223)
        at com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:
77)

Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.tool.ODatabaseExportException: Error
 on importing database 'mydatabase' from file: /home/ubuntu/orientdb_update_16.04.27
.11.10.+0000.gz

Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OLowDiskSpaceException: Error
 occurred while executing a write operation to database 'mydatabase' due to limited
free space on the disk (-26 MB). The database is now working in read-only mode.
Please close the database (or stop OrientDB), make room on your hard drive and t
hen reopen the database. The minimal required space is 100 MB. Required space is
 now set to 100MB (you can change it by setting parameter storage.diskCache.disk
FreeSpaceLimit) .
```

The weird thing is I have plenty of free space available. Running 'df -h' returns:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            492M   12K  492M   1% /dev
tmpfs           100M  336K   99M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  2.2G  5.2G  30% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            497M     0  497M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

Why is OrientDB convinced I have less than 100MB of free space, when in fact I have over 5GB?

EDIT: here is my configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<orient-server>
    <handlers>
        <handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.handler.OGraphServerHandler">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="true" name="enabled"/>
                <parameter value="50" name="graph.pool.max"/>
            </parameters>
        </handler>
        <handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="${DISTRIBUTED}" name="enabled"/>
                <parameter value="${ORIENTDB_HOME}/config/distributed-db-config.json" name="configuration.db.default"/>
                <parameter value="${ORIENTDB_HOME}/config/hazelcast.xml" name="configuration.hazelcast"/>
            </parameters>
        </handler>
        <handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.handler.OJMXPlugin">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="false" name="enabled"/>
                <parameter value="true" name="profilerManaged"/>
            </parameters>
        </handler>
        <handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.handler.OAutomaticBackup">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="false" name="enabled"/>
                <parameter value="4h" name="delay"/>
                <parameter value="backup" name="target.directory"/>
                <parameter value="${DBNAME}-${DATE:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.zip" name="target.fileName"/>
                <parameter value="9" name="compressionLevel"/>
                <parameter value="1048576" name="bufferSize"/>
                <parameter value="" name="db.include"/>
                <parameter value="" name="db.exclude"/>
            </parameters>
        </handler>
        <handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.handler.OServerSideScriptInterpreter">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="true" name="enabled"/>
                <parameter value="SQL" name="allowedLanguages"/>
            </parameters>
        </handler>
        <handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.token.OrientTokenHandler">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="false" name="enabled"/>
                <parameter value="" name="oAuth2Key"/>
                <parameter value="60" name="sessionLength"/>
                <parameter value="HmacSHA256" name="encryptionAlgorithm"/>
            </parameters>
        </handler>
        <handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.livequery.OLiveQueryPlugin">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="false" name="enabled"/>
            </parameters>
        </handler>
    </handlers>
    <network>
        <sockets>
            <socket implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.OServerSSLSocketFactory" name="ssl">
                <parameters>
                    <parameter value="false" name="network.ssl.clientAuth"/>
                    <parameter value="config/cert/orientdb.ks" name="network.ssl.keyStore"/>
                    <parameter value="password" name="network.ssl.keyStorePassword"/>
                    <parameter value="config/cert/orientdb.ks" name="network.ssl.trustStore"/>
                    <parameter value="password" name="network.ssl.trustStorePassword"/>
                </parameters>
            </socket>
            <socket implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.OServerSSLSocketFactory" name="https">
                <parameters>
                    <parameter value="false" name="network.ssl.clientAuth"/>
                    <parameter value="config/cert/orientdb.ks" name="network.ssl.keyStore"/>
                    <parameter value="password" name="network.ssl.keyStorePassword"/>
                    <parameter value="config/cert/orientdb.ks" name="network.ssl.trustStore"/>
                    <parameter value="password" name="network.ssl.trustStorePassword"/>
                </parameters>
            </socket>
        </sockets>
        <protocols>
            <protocol implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary" name="binary"/>
            <protocol implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.ONetworkProtocolHttpDb" name="http"/>
        </protocols>
        <listeners>
            <listener protocol="binary" socket="default" port-range="2424-2430" ip-address="0.0.0.0"/>
            <listener protocol="http" socket="default" port-range="2480-2490" ip-address="0.0.0.0">
                <commands>
                    <command implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.command.get.OServerCommandGetStaticContent" pattern="GET|www GET|studio/ GET| GET|*.htm GET|*.html GET|*.xml GET|*.jpeg GET|*.jpg GET|*.png GET|*.gif GET|*.js GET|*.css GET|*.swf GET|*.ico GET|*.txt GET|*.otf GET|*.pjs GET|*.svg GET|*.json GET|*.woff GET|*.woff2 GET|*.ttf GET|*.svgz" stateful="false">
                        <parameters>
                            <entry value="Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate\r\nPragma: no-cache" name="http.cache:*.htm *.html"/>
                            <entry value="Cache-Control: max-age=120" name="http.cache:default"/>
                        </parameters>
                    </command>
                    <command implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.server.command.OServerCommandGetGephi" pattern="GET|gephi/*" stateful="false"/>
                </commands>
                <parameters>
                    <parameter value="utf-8" name="network.http.charset"/>
                    <parameter value="true" name="network.http.jsonResponseError"/>
                </parameters>
            </listener>
        </listeners>
    </network>
    <storages/>
    <users>
        <user resources="*" password="..." name="root"/>
        <user resources="connect,server.listDatabases,server.dblist" password="guest" name="guest"/>
    </users>
    <properties>
        <entry value="1" name="db.pool.min"/>
        <entry value="50" name="db.pool.max"/>
        <entry value="true" name="profiler.enabled"/>
        <entry value="info" name="log.console.level"/>
        <entry value="fine" name="log.file.level"/>
    </properties>
</orient-server>
```

Comment: Hi, could you  list configuration settings are used by OrientDB ?

Comment: @AndreyLomakin Thanks for asking, I added my configuration details. Note that the problem stopped occurring without me changing anything for some reason, but I still want to know why it happened.